# Iterate with Ansible with_dict over list of a dictionaries

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am stuck in iterating over the list of a dictionary. Sample vars.yml and the minimal playbook is bellow.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  become: false
  vars:
    csvfile: "{{ lookup('file', 'vars/users.csv') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Convert CSV to YAML
      template:
        src: "./users_csv.j2"
        dest: "vars/users.yml"
      run_once: true

    - name: Include users from users.yml to users variable
      include_vars:
        file: vars/users.yml
        name: users

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ users.value }}"
      with_dict:
        - "{{ users }}"
```

My Jinja2 template produces a list of dictionaries in YAML format as below:

```
--
users:
  - username: Auser1
    group: Admin
  - username: Auser2
    group: Admin
  - username: Auser3
    group: User
```

Anyhow, when I am iterating the dictionary, I am not able to get for example a username or group.

Most far I got is getting a fatal error message saying:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "with_dict expects a dict"}
```

I know how to iterate over the list, but I don't have an idea why it fails here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `users` is not a dictionary, its a list variable of dictionaries.

if you want to parse this variable in a loop, you can use:

```
- debug:
    msg: "username: {{ item.username }}, group: {{ item.group }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ users.users }}"
```

hope it helps

**UPDATE**

i noticed now that when including the var file, you pass the `name: users` instruction as well. this cause all the variables of the file to be placed under the `users` variable. So to refer to the `users` list which is defined in the variable file, you need to use `users.users`.

updated the `with_items` to:

```
  with_items:
    - "{{ users.users }}"
```

Comment: That is what I tried initially. Still, it fails with fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'username'\n\n

Comment: oh, i noticed something i had overlooked before. please check updated answer

Comment: Oh, you are correct. I am sure that I haven't used the name: before, or to be more precise I have accessed the vars file directly.

Comment: Perhaps you added as you were testing things? if you dont have other variables in that var file, then it doesnt make much sense to add the `name:` clause as well i guess